# Insert new row in UITableView when tapping first row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm new to iOS development. Therefore it would be nice if your answer could be as detailed as possible. My problem is the following: I want the cell in my second section to always say "add new row". If you click this cell a new row should be added on top. My current code is

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

// Return the number of sections.
return 2;
 }
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
if (section == 0) {
    return 1;
}
else {

    return [entries count];
}
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath        *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
static NSString *todayTableIdentifier = @"Notification";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView       dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
UITableViewCell *todaycell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:todayTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


}
NSString *entry;
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    entry = [notifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell = todaycell;
} else {
    entry = [entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
cell.textLabel.text = entry;

return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

int selectedRow = indexPath.row;
NSLog(@"row pressed %d", selectedRow);
NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:
                  [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:2]];
if (selectedRow == 0)
{   [entries addObject:@"a new Entry"];
    [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}
else {
    [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:paths
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, my app keeps crashing.

```
2013-04-11 16:52:39.717 MyStore[12924:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView    _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:861
2013-04-11 16:52:39.718 MyStore[12924:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception '    NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 2 from section 2, but there    are only 2 sections before the update'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1faa012 0x13e7e7e 0x1fa9e78 0xb6d665 0xbb43c 0xca1f6 0xca271 0x5c6b 0xcb285 0xcb4ed    0xad55b3 0x1f69376 0x1f68e06 0x1f50a82 0x1f4ff44 0x1f4fe1b 0x1f047e3 0x1f04668 0x1bffc 0x21bd  0x20e5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's normal, besides adding a new row (visually), you need to update your Data Source (the notifications array in this case). The UI is just the visualization of your Data Source. So:

```
[notifications addObject:@"a new Entry"];

[[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

And when you delete:

```
 [notifications removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:paths
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

Comment: I tried your code..did you mean to put it in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath? If so, I get an error saying: 'No visible @interface for NSArray declares the selector 'addObject'' I declare the array like so : (at)implementation SettingsViewController
{ 
    NSArray *notifications;
    NSArray *entries;
}

Comment: Declare notifications as an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Thanks, but now my console says: attempt to insert row 3 into section 2, but there are only 2 sections after the update. I 've got 2 section. I want to insert my row in the second one. The second one contains 2 Rows.

Comment: I still get an error...I changed the array to a mutable one..what do you not understand?

Comment: attempt to insert row 3 into section 2, but there are only 2 sections after the update...that's the error message.

Comment: It should be `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1]];`Two sections.... Index 0 and 1...