# Insert New cell dynamically below the current cell, when a Plus Button is pressed

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like to insert a new cell below the current cell, once a plus button is pressed in a tableview. The new cell will be of different height with a UIview as a subview with some custom buttons on it.  upon clicking the plus symbol again , the table collapses.

Is there a specific way in ios to do it easily?

[Insert new row in UITableView when tapping first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950069/insert-new-row-in-uitableview-when-tapping-first-row)

is this the only possible mechanism or is there any simple method?

Comment: what's wrong with the answer in that link. That's the simplest way. Any specific reason for not using that?

Comment: There is nothing wrong, but is there any other method to do this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other methods like you can add or remove object from your array with addObject and  removeObject in didSelectRow and then reload your table. Still I guess simplest way will be to use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`.